# Blob charset for CSV file

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, blob

I would like to create a CSV file using blob. 
The file should be encoded in ANSI, but it doesn't work.

```
var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=windows-1252;' });
```

The file is always created with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: had you answer for this problem?

Comment: @DT could you explain what is wrong with my current answer in your case?

Comment: Your answer can't create a file encoding is ANSI.

Comment: I must download a file with any text, if open in notepad, it have to show encoding ANSI.

Comment: @DT What do you mean? of course it does create a file encoded in ANSI. What's the content of your file? If your file contains only ASCII characters, it doesn't matter if it's read as ASCII, ANSI or UTF-8, all ASCII characters are represented the same way by these three encodings. And what notepad says is how it thought the file was encoded,not necessarily how it was encoded.

Comment: Ex: i output text [this is test-20～15.5] to a file csv with encoding ANSI. Result the same image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n4CjxaG8K699jvVV0UqgDsXBHFo2ZQQV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you link to this text file? I think we already met, and I already told you that `～` character can't be represented in ANSI. So either your text editor lies to you, either it's not the text you have in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224708/discussion-between-d-t-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 2):

Passing an [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) (or a JavaScript string) to the [Blob's constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) will [automatically encode it to *UTF-8*](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#process-blob-parts) in the Blob's data.

The `type` option is only used by *resource fetchers*, it serves to mimick the `Content-Type` header of an HTTP request.
So for instance if you fetch or serve that Blob through a `blob://` URI, this `type`'s value will be used, similarly if you call a FileReader's `readAsText( blob )` method without the *encoding* second parameter, the `charset=` info there may be used.

**But this `type` option doesn't change at all the *content* of the Blob's data.**

```js
(async ()=> {

  const data = "é";
  const no_type = new Blob( [ data ] );
  const csv_windows1252 = new Blob( [ data ], { type: "text/csv;charset=Windows-1252" } );
  const image_png = new Blob( [ data ], { type: "image/png" } );

  // read as ArrayBuffer to see the exact binary content
  console.log( "no_type:", await hexDump( no_type ) ); // C3A9
  console.log( "csv_windows1252:", await hexDump( csv_windows1252 ) ); // C3A9
  console.log( "image_png:", await hexDump( image_png ) ); // C3A9

})();

async function hexDump( blob ) {
  const buf = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  const view = new Uint8Array( buf );
  const arr = [ ... view ];
  return arr.map( (val) => val.toString( 16 ) )
    .join( "" ).toUpperCase();
}
```

As you can see in this snippet, no matter the `type` parameter, all these Blobs hold exactly the same bytes data: `C3 A9` which corresponds to the **UTF-8** representation of an [`é` (U+00e9)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) character "*UTF-8 (hex)     0xC3 0xA9 (c3a9)*".
In [ANSI (Windows-1252)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set), this character is represented by the byte *0xe9 (e9)*, so if our Blob did hold our text encoded in ANSI, it should contain this byte.

One way to see it is to use a [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) and try to decode both Blobs using both encodings:

```js
const UTF8Content = new Uint8Array( [ 0xC3, 0xA9 ] );
const ANSIContent = new Uint8Array( [ 0xE9 ] );

const UTF8Decoder = new TextDecoder( "utf-8" );
const ANSIDecoder = new TextDecoder( "windows-1252" );

console.log( "UTF8-content decoded as UTF8",
  UTF8Decoder.decode( UTF8Content )
); // é
console.log( "UTF8-content decoded as ANSI",
  ANSIDecoder.decode( UTF8Content )
); // Ã©
console.log( "ANSI-content decoded as UTF8",
  UTF8Decoder.decode( ANSIContent )
); // �
console.log( "ANSI-content decoded as ANSI",
  ANSIDecoder.decode( ANSIContent )
); // é
```

---

So for what you wish, you'd need to generate your Blobs from a TypedArray that contains your data already encoded in ANSI.
There used to be an option using the [TextEncoder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder) to encode from USVStrings to arbitrary encodings, but this has been removed from specs and browsers.

So the easiest is to use a library in order to perform the conversion. Here, I'll use [this one](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding):

```js
const text = "é";
const data = new TextEncoder( "windows-1252", {
  NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true
} ).encode( text ); // now `data` is an Uint8Array

const blob = new Blob( [ "foo bar" ], { type: "text/csv" } ); // here you have your ANSI Blob

// Just to be sure
hexDump( blob ).then( console.log ); // E9

async function hexDump( blob ) {
  const buf = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  const view = new Uint8Array( buf );
  const arr = [ ...view ];
  return arr.map( (val) => val.toString( 16 ) )
    .join( "" ).toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<script>
  // we need to force installation of the library
  // by removing the built-in API
  window.TextEncoder = null;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding-indexes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding.js"></script>
```

[As a fiddle with the *download* link](https://jsfiddle.net/fav7qyL6/) since stack-snippets aren't allowed to do so anymore.

---

#### Important note:

ANSI supports only a limited set of characters, some characters that can be held in an USVString can't be mapped to ANSI, so **you must be sure your input will only contain mappable characters or it will throw**:

```js
const text = ""; // can't be mapped to ANSI
const data = new TextEncoder( "windows-1252", {
  NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true
} ).encode( text ); // throws
```

```html
<script>
  window.TextEncoder = null;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding-indexes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding.js"></script>
```

---

**Ps:** the `\uFEFF` character you did prepend to the Blob's data in your code is an UTF-16 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It only helps the reader know the intended endianness of the data for UTF-16 encoded text, it doesn't encode the following data in any way, and it doesn't help at all in non UTF-16 files.

Comment: This answer is so detailed.. brilliant!

Comment: A mistake in **Ps**? `\uFFFE` isn't a valid Unicode character. UTF-16 BOM is `\uFEFF`  (U+FEFF,  *Zero Width No-Break Space*).

Comment: @JosefZ indeed thanks for the heads up.